# How to get excel to delete something from one list if it's in another list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two lists in excel, let's call them B and A. if there is an email in list A that matches an email form list A I need to delete it. I could do this manually but that would be weeks of work. There's got to be a way to get excel to do it for me.

EDIT/UPDATE

[here is a pic of situation/problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYSnM.png)

I know nothing about Excel, so the first thing I would like to do is to remove any duplicates from within the lists themselves. but then I would also like any contacts/emails from list B that has a duplicate in list A to be removed. for example, if the email John@John.com is in list B and there is also a John@john.com in list A, I want to remove John@john.com from list B

Comment: "...need to delete it" - Delete which one, the one in A, or the one in B? Do you want to delete the cell, or just clear the data?  What if the email appears multiple times in A? What if it appears multiple times in B?  What have you tried? There's the "Remove Duplicates" option in Excel, if the emails would be side-by-side...

Comment: A formula will not do this,  You can create a third list that only has the values from one that are not in the other, but a formula cannot delete another cells value.  You will need vba if you want to delete in place.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use vlookup (or match/index if you have millions of emails, it's faster).  Add a column in the sheet with the emails to be managed called "Keep", add a formula to set it to TRUE if the email is in the inactive list, or false if it's not.  You can then filter the list to only the rows where Keep is FALSE, and delete those rows.  One tip with vlookup - if you highlight the range of inactive emails and name the range (in the screenshot below, click in the top left where it says B2 and type in "Inactive"), then you can use that name in the vlookup formula, which makes life easier.  Really needs to be a video ;-)

E.g.

[image]

Comment: I think that would work, here is a pic of what I'm working with. [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs0O4.jpg Could you give me code that would work? I tried messing around with this code in your pic but I couldn't get it to work. It would just give me one T or F instead of a list of them.